# The photo taken by my webcam isn't the same as previewed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, camera, webcam

I'm having a trouble while using my camera inside a webpage. The problem is that the previewed photo is not the same as the photo that is actually taken.

Here is a image showing the issue (the picture on the left is the previewed one and the right one is the picture actually taken) : [image]
And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/darzang/qhxgjq4h/2/) is a jsFiddle with my code .

I don't really know where this issue can come from, maybe this line `context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);`  ?

Also I'd like to add that the issue is the same on a few computers, phones and tablets I had under hand (By the way do we say under hand or on hand ? )

It's the first time i'm using a webcam inside my apps so I'm kinda lost, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance and have a great day !

Comment: I looks like there is a significant delay between the live preview and the captured image. I suggest that you use a digital watch for testing, then you will easily see what the delay is, and whether it is consistent.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand well, i should count the time between the moment i press the button and the moment my picture appears on the right ?

Comment: You will have two clocks on your screen, and can compare the "preview" clock and the "captured" clock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a collegue and I manage to get it working, we had to change the sizes of the two div so that they match the same dimensions.